# Can't I add static values to native javascript Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm iterating through an array of objects to build a collection of Promises that I want to await in parallel. I need a specific property (unrelated to the promise) to persist in the result, but I can't just add it as a property of the Promise, it gets wiped away when the promise resolves:

```
let arrayOPromises = someArrayOfValues.map((promiseParams) => {
   let response = someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(promiseParams);
   response.valueINeedToPersist = promiseParams.objectPropertyINeed; //unique to each iteration of map()
   return response;
});

await Promise.all(arrayOPromises);

// gives me the resolved promises, but not the added value

// [resolvedPromise1, resolvedPromise2];

// resolvedPromise1.valueINeedToPersist === 'undefined'
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  `objectPropertyINeed` as you have it shown would be an `index` from the call to `.map()` and it would be different for every iteration of the `.map()` loop.  So, are you just trying to save the index with the result for each item in the loop?  Or what?  The end of your question makes it look like there's only one `objectPropertyINeed`, but the way you show it, there would be N of them.

Comment: Can you show the real code, not pseudo-code.  I think you've over simplified in the pseudo-code and thus don't show the real problem.  If all you need is the `.map()` index, then that's already available as the result index from `Promise.all()` since the result array is in the same order as the `.map()` iteration.  But, if `objectPropertyINeed` is more complicated than that, then we need to see the REAL code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah, great catch. It's a unique value for every iteration (so assume it's the index, I forgot that the 2nd argument for `.map` is the index)

Comment: So, do you see that you can just get the index from the `Promise.all().then(results => { code here })` results array?  You don't need to store it?

Comment: What is the resolved value of the `response` promise?  Is it an object?  Or a primitive?  The answer depends upon that info.  If it's a primitive, then you have to wrap two values in another object and make the resolved value of the promise be that object.  If it's already an object, you can just add the property to that object in a `.then()` handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 The resolved value is an object, so the answer below by Bergi seems to be the correct way to add the value in my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need a specific property (unrelated to the promise) to persist in the result

Yes, then do add it to the result and not to the promise object:

```
const arrayOPromises = someArrayOfValues.map(async (promiseParams, objectPropertyINeed) => {
   const response = await someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise(promiseParams);
//                  ^^^^^
   response.valueINeedToPersist = objectPropertyINeed;
   return response;
});

await Promise.all(arrayOPromises);
```

Comment: I think `response` should be `let response` since we are modifying it below, but this answer is correct otherwise.

Comment: @AustinMeyers -  For completeness, you can also do this with a `.then()` handler.  Don't need to use `async/await`.  Either way works.  Also `const` refers to assigning to the variable itself, not to modifying properties on the value.  `const` would work just fine here.  For example, you can do this just fine: `const x = {foo: "bar"};  x.greeting = "hello";`

Comment: @AustinMeyers he's not reassigning response, so there's no need for let. He's just modifying a property.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification on `const` as well

Comment: `await Promise.all(arrayOPromises);` needs to be inside an `async` right?

Comment: @robe007 Yes. I would assume the OP does that, as he already uses `await` in his question